# "Yesterday I should help him do the dishes"

Tags: word-choice, past-tense, auxiliary-verbs

> "Yesterday I should help him do the dishes"

I'm pretty sure that using "should" here is wrong and "had to" would have to be used instead (Yesterday I had to help him do the dishes) but why?

Comment: Do you mean "Yesterday, I should have helped him do the dishes", or "Yesterday, I helped him do the dishes because I was required to"?  The first version implies that you did not help do the dishes, and the second version implies that you did help do the dishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use *should* in the past tense, but usually the structure would be something like:

> Yesterday I **should have helped** him do the dishes (but I was playing video games instead)

As written, you example is incorrect.  Some other examples of should:

> I should help him do the dishes (right now)
>
> I should help him do the dishes this evening.
>
> I should have gone to school yesterday (but I didn't).

Remember that *should* implies "obligation" while *have to* implies either "requirement" or "demand".  They aren't the same thing.

> I should clean up this mess (I am obligated to do it)
>
> I have to clean up this mess (I am required to / forced to do it)

Comment: thanks is "had to" the best option in my sentence if I actually helped him?( If you were expected to help and did but were not forced to help)

Comment: @ChadThunder "had to" means that you were (in some way) *forced* to do it.  If this is not the case then you should say simply, "I helped him with the dishes."  But you are correct that "should have done" implies you *didn't* do it.